# PHP processes not dying

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a site running on godaddy hosting (yes I know...) that holds up to 100 concurrent php processes. Lately the site has started receiving 503 errors and the processes max out.

I know this has been discussed before in relevance to Wordpress but thats the kicker... I am not running WP nor am I using mysql_pconnect. The processes just stay and stack up until I manually kill them.

I connect to a database and run 3-4 select statements and thats all. Godaddy support was useless and I have no log of what script is calling the process.

Without a in depth analysis of the code or being able to see certain logs what steps can I take in order to narrow down what is causing the issue? It occurs randomly through the day and doesn't match up to high usage either. I can have 130 users with no problems but get 503 errors with 30 users.

Thanks for any help as I am pulling out my hair...

**UPDATE:**
Finally got access to view processes and stats. The processes are definitely going over the time limit on the server. Talked to server support and they said there is an issue with a few boxes that they have added my server into that issue list. Crossing fingers but doubting that will be the fix.

I ran an strace -p on a process that ran for 10 minutes... the trace shows it basically going from page to page... pausing then accessing another page. I tied that process to a google bot. Is that normal? Out of 53 processes active 52 were sleeping.. These sleepers go from anywhere to 20 seconds to 10 minutes. running a trace on a few showed a LOCK( which i assume means it is pausing to receive. You will notice when running 'top' the php process that is sticking... this one when traced just loads a page, sleeps on a timer, loads another page... This is when my site is dead so you can imagine when it is busy to have these processes running for so long. I have no scripts or anything that do such a thing on the site. I have a long trace report that i can message or email but is too long to post here.

```
top - 17:31:58 up 6 days,  9:17,  0 users,  load average: 6.16, 7.77, 7.15
Tasks:   8 total,   1 running,   7 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 16.1%us,  7.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 70.6%id,  6.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32741960k total, 27249096k used,  5492864k free,  1930272k buffers
Swap:  8388604k total,        0k used,  8388604k free, 12611492k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 2617 user  20   0  346m  30m  11m S  0.7  0.1   0:06.95 php                
19181 user  20   0  4404  784  676 S  0.7  0.0   0:01.80 strace             
11404 user  20   0  105m 1936  948 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 sshd               
11410 user  20   0 11476 1680 1348 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 bash               
15425 user  20   0 14908 1148  960 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.49 top                
17913 user  20   0  105m 1944  948 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.32 sshd               
17945 user  20   0 11476 1672 1348 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash               
24294 user  20   0  332m  16m  10m S  0.0  0.1   0:01.14 php
```

Comment: That only seems to compound the problem.. Adds another entry process that won't close.. Does accessing DOMDocument throw up a process that could be sticking? I access it to cycle through headline tags...

Comment: Sorry for double post.. Is there anything in htaccess such as mod_rewrite that could be an issue? Entry processes also shoot up even though nothing is written to database...

Comment: What are these concurrent processes? Is it part of a job queue? Beanstalk jobs, for example, need to destroy themselves after they finish. Without logs, there's not a whole lot that can be done.

Comment: They aren't part of a job queue just normal php processes when loading a page such as a select statement and a few includes.. I updated the post with some log information.

Comment: The log information we need to help debug for you isn't a `top` dump. But log files, such as those in `/var/log/apache2/`, or `[somewhere]/src/your_project/app/log/`, etc. You can upload them to pastebin, or similar.